# Slow SQL SELECT for specific key values

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, select, sql-server-2012

Why is there such a difference in time for these two queries?

This query takes about 51 seconds to complete:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * 
FROM [PHONER].[dbo].[V_PhonerSubjects]
WHERE ProjectID = 137;
```

However, this Query takes about 1 second to complete:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * 
FROM [PHONER].[dbo].[V_PhonerSubjects]
WHERE ProjectID = 107;
```

Notice: The only difference is the value of the key.

Both have a total of more than 1000 records. Project 107 has 26000 records and project 137 has 4500 records.

`ProjectID` is an indexed primary key.

I have noticed that for the second query finishes and sends all rows to result window in 1 second. The first Query starts to send rows after about 3 seconds and is finished after around 51 seconds.

This is the SQL of the View `V_PhonerSubjects`:

```
SELECT        
   dbo.PhonerEmner.PhonerEmID AS SubjectID, dbo.PhonerEmner.FK_ProID AS ProjectID, 
   dbo.PhonerProjekt.PhonerTitel AS ProjectName, dbo.Medlemsdata.Vennenr AS FriendNo, 
   dbo.Medlemsdata.OpretteDato AS CreatedDate, dbo.Medlemsdata.OpretteID AS CreatedID, 
   dbo.Bruger.Intialer AS CreatedBy, dbo.Medlemsdata.ÆndretDato AS ChangedDate, 
   dbo.Medlemsdata.ÆndretID AS ChangedID,  
   Bruger_3.Intialer AS ChangedBy, 
   ISNULL(dbo.Medlemsdata.Organisation, N'') + N' ' + ISNULL(dbo.Medlemsdata.Fornavn, N'') + N' ' + ISNULL(dbo.Medlemsdata.Efternavn, N'') AS Name, 
   dbo.MedlemsAdresse.AdrID AS AddressID, dbo.MedlemsAdresse.Adresse AS Address1, 
   dbo.MedlemsAdresse.Adresse2 AS Address2, dbo.MedlemsAdresse.Postnr AS ZIP, 
   dbo.Postnumre.[By] AS City, dbo.Medlemsdata.CPRnr AS CPRno, 
   dbo.Medlemsdata.Køn AS Gender, dbo.Medlemsdata.Telefon AS Phone01, 
   dbo.Medlemsdata.TlfNote1 AS Phone02Type, dbo.Medlemsdata.Tlf1 AS Phone02, 
   dbo.Medlemsdata.TlfNote2 AS Phone03Type, dbo.Medlemsdata.Tlf2 AS Phone03, 
   dbo.Medlemsdata.TlfNote3 AS Phone04Type, 
   dbo.Medlemsdata.Tlf3 AS Phone04, dbo.Medlemsdata.TlfSMS AS PhoneMobile, 
   dbo.Medlemsdata.[E-mail] AS Email, dbo.Medlemsdata.SPFelt1 AS SPField01,
   dbo.Medlemsdata.SPFelt2 AS SPField02, dbo.Medlemsdata.SPFelt3 AS SPField03, 
   dbo.Medlemsdata.SPFelt4 AS SPField04, dbo.Medlemsdata.SPFelt5 AS SPField05, 
   dbo.Medlemsdata.SPFelt6 AS SPField06, dbo.Medlemsdata.SPFelt7 AS SPField07, 
   dbo.Medlemsdata.SPFelt8 AS SPField08, dbo.Medlemsdata.SPFelt9 AS SPField09, 
   dbo.Medlemsdata.SPFelt10 AS SPField10, dbo.Medlemsdata.SPFelt11 AS SPField11, 
   dbo.Medlemsdata.SPFelt12 AS SPField12, dbo.Medlemsdata.SPFelt13 AS SPField13, 
   dbo.Medlemsdata.SPFelt14 AS SPField14, dbo.PhonerEmner.SidsteKontakt AS LastContact, 
   dbo.PhonerEmner.AntalKontakt AS ContactTimes, dbo.PhonerEmner.KontaktDage AS ContactDays, 
   dbo.PhonerEmner.KontaktEfter AS ContactAfter, 
   dbo.PhonerEmner.PhonerIgen AS ContactAfterPhonerID, 
   Bruger_1.Navn AS ContactAfterPhonerName, dbo.PhonerEmner.PhonerNote, 
   dbo.PhonerEmner.Stemning AS Mood, dbo.PhonerEmner.Status, 
   dbo.PhonerEmner.PhonerAft AS LastPhonerID, Bruger_2.Navn AS LastPhonerName, 
   dbo.PhonerEmner.SlutNote AS EndNote, dbo.PhonerEmner.SlutDato AS EndDate, 
   dbo.PhonerImport.PhonerImportID AS ImportID, dbo.PhonerImportData.Status AS ImportStatus, 
   dbo.PhonerImport.ImportFileName, dbo.PhonerImport.ImportTime, 
   dbo.PhonerProjekt.SvarerIkkeTid
FROM            
   dbo.Bruger AS Bruger_1 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.PhonerProjekt 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.PhonerEmner ON dbo.PhonerProjekt.PhonerProID = dbo.PhonerEmner.FK_ProID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.PhonerImportData ON dbo.PhonerEmner.PhonerEmID = dbo.PhonerImportData.FK_PhonerEmID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.Bruger AS Bruger_2 ON dbo.PhonerEmner.PhonerAft = Bruger_2.BrugerID ON Bruger_1.BrugerID = dbo.PhonerEmner.PhonerIgen 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.Bruger 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.Bruger AS Bruger_3 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.Medlemsdata ON Bruger_3.BrugerID = dbo.Medlemsdata.ÆndretID ON dbo.Bruger.BrugerID = dbo.Medlemsdata.OpretteID ON dbo.PhonerEmner.FK_Vennenr = dbo.Medlemsdata.Vennenr 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.Postnumre 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.MedlemsAdresse ON dbo.Postnumre.Postnummer = dbo.MedlemsAdresse.Postnr ON dbo.Medlemsdata.FK_AdrID = dbo.MedlemsAdresse.AdrID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.PhonerImport ON dbo.PhonerImportData.FK_PhonerImportID = dbo.PhonerImport.PhonerImportID
```

Client statistics for project 107:

```
Client Execution Time   14:04:24        
Query Profile Statistics            
  Number of INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE statements    0       0.0000
  Rows affected by INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statements 0       0.0000
  Number of SELECT statements   2       2.0000
  Rows returned by SELECT statements    1001        1001.0000
  Number of transactions    0       0.0000
Network Statistics          
  Number of server roundtrips   3       3.0000
  TDS packets sent from client  3       3.0000
  TDS packets received from server  241     241.0000
  Bytes sent from client    340     340.0000
  Bytes received from server    976874      976874.0000
Time Statistics         
  Client processing time    95      95.0000
  Total execution time  391     391.0000
  Wait time on server replies   296     296.0000
```

Client statistics for project 137:

```
Client Execution Time   13:58:28        
Query Profile Statistics            
  Number of INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE statements    0       0.0000
  Rows affected by INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statements 0       0.0000
  Number of SELECT statements   2       2.0000
  Rows returned by SELECT statements    1001        1001.0000
  Number of transactions    0       0.0000
Network Statistics          
  Number of server roundtrips   3       3.0000
  TDS packets sent from client  3       3.0000
  TDS packets received from server  217     217.0000
  Bytes sent from client    340     340.0000
  Bytes received from server    877700      877700.0000
Time Statistics         
  Client processing time    129596      129596.0000
  Total execution time  130297      130297.0000
  Wait time on server replies   701     701.0000
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you provide the query execution plan for both statements separately. In SQL Management Studio, select the icon for "Include Actual Execution Plan" (or use Ctrl + M to toggle it), and grab the execution plan after the query completes, which will be available as a tab labeled "Execution plan" in the query results pane. What do those execution plans look like for each query individually?

Comment: Out of date statistics perhaps?  in the execution plan check the estimated row vs actual rows returned

Comment: Please post the 2 query plan.

Comment: You have the comment that: "ProjectID is an indexed primary key."  However, the `ProjectID` value that is being returned in the view `V_PhonerSubjects` is `dbo.PhonerEmner.FK_ProID AS ProjectID`, which I'm assuming is not the primary key, but a foreign key back to the `dbo.PhonerProjekt` table.  If you change `dbo.PhonerEmner.FK_ProID AS ProjectID` to `dbo.PhonerProjekt.PhonerProID AS ProjectID` in the view, does that help?

Comment: You are right that "fk_" denotes foreign key. However, it is still part of the primary key. It's part of a shared key consisting of Vennenr and FK_ProID. So one friend can be part of several projects. But only once in each project. I did try your suggestion though, with no effect.

Comment: I have made the exceution plans and it looks like the problem is with the import files to my untrained eye. But how do I post them here? If I try to post the xml I get a error message saying it's too long. I can not seem to find any option to attach a file.

Comment: I found a difference in the execution plans. When it looks in PhonerImportData it estimates 1 execution in both cases. But the number of executions is 4 in the fast one and 1000 (one for each record) for the slow one. If this is the problem then how do I fix it? It says "Clustered Index Scan" with a cost of 8% and 55%.

Answer (score 1):

Your complex mess of left and right joins, along with the very unassociated readability of your query could very well be part of the problems.  I could be completely wrong and accept that.  However, I restructured your query based on all the hierarchical join criteria from each respective table to the next... With each table "JOIN"ed and "ON" condition directly as associated vs intermixed.  Here, you can see hierarchically how the tables relate to get to the necessary details.  I also used ALIASES for better readability from the original post.

So, it appears you have some phone projects joined to a PhonerEmner table.  Based on those elements, you are trying to pull as much lookup secondary data as possible. IF it exists, great, get it, but don't stop if no such record found in the child-level related tables.  This way, they are all LEFT JOINs.  If you want records to be REQUIRED in any given table, just change from a LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN, and/or add a WHERE clause to ensure a given alias.ID column IS found.

All that said, I would make sure the tables have indexes to properly optimize the joins via..

```
table            index
PhonerEmner      (FK_ProID, PhonerIgen, PhonerEmID, PhonerAft, FK_Vennenr
PhonerProjekt    (PhonerProID)
Bruger           (BrugerID
PhonerImportData (FK_PhonerEmID, FK_PhonerImportID
PhonerImport     (PhonerImportID
Medlemsdata      (Vennenr, OpretteID, ÆndretID, FK_AdrID )
MedlemsAdresse   (AdrID, Postnr)
Postnumre        (Postnummer)
```

and came up with this revised query which you could create as a new View to test against.

```
SELECT
      PE.PhonerEmID AS SubjectID, 
      PE.FK_ProID AS ProjectID, 
      PP.PhonerTitel AS ProjectName, 
      MED.Vennenr AS FriendNo, 
      MED.OpretteDato AS CreatedDate, 
      MED.OpretteID AS CreatedID, 
      B.Intialer AS CreatedBy, 
      MED.ÆndretDato AS ChangedDate, 
      MED.ÆndretID AS ChangedID,  
      B3.Intialer AS ChangedBy, 
      ISNULL(MED.Organisation, N'') 
         + N' ' + ISNULL(MED.Fornavn, N'') 
         + N' ' + ISNULL(MED.Efternavn, N'') AS Name, 
      ADR.AdrID AS AddressID, 
      ADR.Adresse AS Address1, 
      ADR.Adresse2 AS Address2, 
      ADR.Postnr AS ZIP, 
      PST.[By] AS City, 
      MED.CPRnr AS CPRno, 
      MED.Køn AS Gender, 
      MED.Telefon AS Phone01, 
      MED.TlfNote1 AS Phone02Type, 
      MED.Tlf1 AS Phone02, 
      MED.TlfNote2 AS Phone03Type, 
      MED.Tlf2 AS Phone03, 
      MED.TlfNote3 AS Phone04Type, 
      MED.Tlf3 AS Phone04, 
      MED.TlfSMS AS PhoneMobile, 
      MED.[E-mail] AS Email, 
      MED.SPFelt1 AS SPField01,
      MED.SPFelt2 AS SPField02, 
      MED.SPFelt3 AS SPField03, 
      MED.SPFelt4 AS SPField04, 
      MED.SPFelt5 AS SPField05, 
      MED.SPFelt6 AS SPField06, 
      MED.SPFelt7 AS SPField07, 
      MED.SPFelt8 AS SPField08, 
      MED.SPFelt9 AS SPField09, 
      MED.SPFelt10 AS SPField10, 
      MED.SPFelt11 AS SPField11, 
      MED.SPFelt12 AS SPField12, 
      MED.SPFelt13 AS SPField13, 
      MED.SPFelt14 AS SPField14, 
      PE.SidsteKontakt AS LastContact, 
      PE.AntalKontakt AS ContactTimes, 
      PE.KontaktDage AS ContactDays, 
      PE.KontaktEfter AS ContactAfter, 
      PE.PhonerIgen AS ContactAfterPhonerID, 
      B1.Navn AS ContactAfterPhonerName, 
      PE.PhonerNote, 
      PE.Stemning AS Mood, 
      PE.Status, 
      PE.PhonerAft AS LastPhonerID, 
      B2.Navn AS LastPhonerName, 
      PE.SlutNote AS EndNote, 
      PE.SlutDato AS EndDate, 
      PI.PhonerImportID AS ImportID, 
      PID.Status AS ImportStatus, 
      PI.ImportFileName, PI.ImportTime, 
      PP.SvarerIkkeTid
   FROM
      dbo.PhonerEmner PE
         LEFT JOIN dbo.PhonerProjekt PP
            ON PE.FK_ProID = PP.PhonerProID 
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Bruger B1 
            ON PE.PhonerIgen = B1.BrugerID
         LEFT JOIN dbo.PhonerImportData PID 
            ON PE.PhonerEmID = PID.FK_PhonerEmID
            LEFT JOIN dbo.PhonerImport PI 
               ON PID.FK_PhonerImportID = PI.PhonerImportID
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Bruger B2 
            ON PE.PhonerAft = B2.BrugerID 
         LEFT JOIN dbo.Medlemsdata MED 
            ON PE.FK_Vennenr = MED.Vennenr 
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Bruger B
               ON MED.OpretteID = B.BrugerID
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Bruger B3 
               ON MED.ÆndretID = B3.BrugerID
            LEFT JOIN dbo.MedlemsAdresse ADR 
               ON MED.FK_AdrID = ADR.AdrID 
               LEFT JOIN dbo.Postnumre PST
                  ON ADR.Postnr = PST.Postnummer
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestion and made sure the indexes above was made. No change at all. The reason for the low readability is due to the view designer of Microsoft SQL Management Studio.

Comment: @JackW.Jensen, I understand about designers trying to think for you.. Did you do it as a separate view and queried from that... or did you create the second view but query from the original view.  Sounds bad, but I even have brain cramps sometimes :)

Comment: Its a view that is a basis for a search tool. The search tool builds a where condition and retrieves the result from the view.

Comment: lol only now I understand your comment. I did test against the new view ;-)

Answer (score 0):

given that the fewer rows run slower, I would suspect the data contents, not the schema.

if one dataset finds matches on most OUTER JOINs and the other doesn't, that might account for some of the difference in runtimes.  When joining, a miss just pings the index, but a hit results in a table read.

Comment: This was my first suspicion also. But its more the other way around. For instance project 107 has 35 associated import files, where as project 137 has only 3.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I changed a join. To me it should not matter whether I did it one way or the other but apparently it did.

In stead of joining PhonerEmner to PhonerImportData on PhonerEmID = FK_PhonerEmID. I joined MedlemsData to PhonerImportData on Vennenr = FK_Vennenr. It must have something to do with PhonerEmID not being a primary key but only indexed.